# how to delete or hide placeholder when there is no value

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

i want to ask if input text in row cell that has mask it will show as `1234-5678-9123-456`. and when i try to delete the value why does it still showing the place holder ? `-    -    -    -` how do i delete/hide the place holder ? but when i try to delete it with `CTRL+DEL` it's totally empty the cell value.

```
    Dim x As New Repository.RepositoryItemTextEdit

    x.Mask.MaskType = Mask.MaskType.Simple
    x.Mask.EditMask = "9999-9999-9999-9999"
    x.Mask.PlaceHolder = " " 
    x.AllowNullInput = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True
    x.NullValuePrompt = ""
    x.NullValuePromptShowForEmptyValue = True
    GridControl3.RepositoryItems.Add(x)


    GridView3.Columns("cardNo").VisibleIndex = 1
    GridView3.Columns("cardNo").Width = 150
    GridView3.Columns("cardNo").ColumnEdit = x
```

[image]

Comment: That's what Masks are supposed to do..

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MaskProperties.ShowPlaceHolder documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsMaskMaskProperties_ShowPlaceHolderstopic):

> For the MaskType.Regular and MaskType.Simple mask types placeholders are always visible.

One solution might be to instead use a RegEx mask and toggle the MaskProperties.ShowPlaceHolder property when the control value is null or empty within the [EditValueChanging event handler](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItem_EditValueChangingtopic).